# Circular motion of planet around star

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-gravity, reference-frames, celestial-mechanics

[image]

The question says that the planet moves in a circular orbit around the massive star. But the graph says that velocity of the star wrt the COM of star-planet system varies with time. But my confusion is if the star moves in a circular orbit why the aforesaid velocity varies in magnitude?

Comment: Would the velocity still be constant in the center of mass frame?

Comment: You are right to be confused. It may mean the *projection* of the velocity onto a cartesian axis on the orbital plane? If this is for a class, ask your instructor for clarification.

Comment: @AfterShave velocity of the planet will be v=(GM/R)^1/2. Since star is massive assuming velocity of star to be negligible, I think velocity wrt com reference will be zero

Comment: @gs it came in a college entrance examination in India.

Comment: For future reference if you want people to read text, don't post an image of it (let alone one that requires they twist their necks to read it) and just type text instead.  We strongly discourage images of text as they cannot be searched.

Comment: That's unfortunate for both you and the state of college entrance exams. The question is at best misworded. (Hint: to prove constant (but nonzero!) velocity w/r/t the center of mass for both bodies, argue by equating centripetal force on each body with the force of gravity between the bodies, since circular orbit means $dr/dt = 0$.) If you need to answer with multiple choice, I'd suggest assuming that the question means to ask about the projection of the velocity onto a coplanar cartesian axis.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The velocity of an object in circular motion does change with time, but only its direction. The magnitude does not change. So a strict reading of the question indicates the graph is wrong.

However, from the shape of the graph, we can guess that what's actually plotted is not the velocity, but rather the projection of the velocity onto some axis. In this case the velocity in (say) the $x$-direction is $v_x = v_0 \sin{\theta}$, and you end up with a sine curve, which is what is in the plot. The magnitude of the velocity is $80 m/s$, and a full orbit takes about three days.